# how to add static text in sugarCRM leads form

Tags: sugarcrm

I'm working on the checkbox options for "WORKING DAYS" Mon to Sun. I created all the 7 check boxes with labels Mon to Sun. How can I add "OFFICE WORKING DAYS" static text in form?

Answer (score 0):

By form, are you referring to **editviewdefs/detailviewdefs**?

Here is how I tried on adding static text. I have used this on editviewdefs

```
array (
    0 => array(
         'name' => '',
         'customCode'=> '<p>OFFICE IN WORKING DAYS</p>',
    ),
),

array( 
    0 => array( 
        // this is where the checkboxes fields
    ),
),
```